# Showing random divs images every time page is load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have these images gallery, how do i randomly display the images everytime when i reload the page?

http://creativepreviews.com/fiddle/study/20131007/

Comment: Well have you looked into the [`Math.random()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)? Or one of the [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533829/on-load-of-page-put-random-image-in-div?rq=1) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376442/pulling-out-a-random-image-when-page-loads-every-time?rq=1) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246566/how-do-i-have-a-different-image-load-on-each-page-refresh?rq=1) that already asked something similar?

Comment: hope this link might be useful to you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055079/show-random-images-at-random-places-jquery

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i have seen the code. Very similar and close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something along these lines (not tested)

```
var grd = $('#grid');
var imgs = grd.children();
imgs.sort(function(){return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);});
grd.remove('li');
for(var i=0;i < imgs.length;i++) grd.append(imgs[i]);
```

In essence what we are doing is getting all the li elements in 'grid' into an array, randomizing them, removing them all from 'grid' and then putting them back in again.

If you had supplied a working fiddle rather than a link to the finished article it would be easier to modify it and provide a more complete solution.

Comment: This is better, as it wont generate codes if i have more than 50 pictures. A few lines will just shuffle everything within #ID.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the image will display in the background of the DIV, then the following should do it.

```
// JS

var imgArray = ["img1.jpg", "cat.jpg", "sky.jpg"]

function randomBg() {
    x = Math.random()
    y = Math.round(x * 10)
    if (imgArray[y] != undefined) {
        document.getElementById("blah").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgArray[y] + "')"
    } else {
            document.getElementById("blah").style.backgroundImage = "url('default.jpg')"
    }    
}
```

...and the HTML.

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<body onload="randomBg()">
<div id="blah"></div>
```

...or you could replace the `style.backgroundImage` in the JS with `innerHTML = <img src="` etc...

Comment: Thanks, This is similar and change the background. Will be useful for my certain projects.